# Why was the data on my bot reset, seemingly at random, without any updates or notifications of such?

Tags: crash, bots, reset

I am hosting a clone of a plant discord bot on Heroku, created by Felix Rilling. "Lisa-Bot" This was done in order to avoid the calamities than can occur to the bot,  since it's status is global and users in other servers are not as nice as those in mine.

However, my efforts have been for naught, since the bot crashed, (or something, I'm a relative amateur) and everything was reset, including it's "max lifespan."

Why did this happen and what can I do to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heroku is borked or something and Digital Ocean is a much better alternative. Probably even Glitch is better.